# Selenium - dropdown

Tags: selenium

From and to fields not populating from the dropdown menu

this is my code:

```
public class MyFirst {
public static void main(String[] args)  {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\kunal.bhaskar\\Downloads\\chromedriver.exe");

      WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
      String baseUrl = "https://www.goindigo.in";

      driver.get(baseUrl);


     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")).clear(); 
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")).click();
    Select from = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")));
    from.selectByVisibleText("Delhi");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[2]/input[1]")).click();
    Select to = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[2]/input[1]")));
    to.selectByVisibleText("Patna");
     driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/input")).click();
     Select adult = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/div/div[1]/label[2]/select")));
    adult.selectByVisibleText("2");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"depart-date\"]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"depart-date\"]")).sendKeys("18 Oct 2017");
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"return-date\"]")).clear();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"return-date\"]")).sendKeys("28 Oct 2017");

    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/div/div/div/ul/li[2]/div/div[1]")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[2]/button")).click();

}
```

Comment: It is not a drop down

Comment: Then how to select any city from the given options

Comment: I will provide u code

Comment: Try this code dear

Comment: Your question doesn't contain a question. What are you asking?

Comment: @BryanOakley give me the reason for -ve vote

Comment: @iamsankalp89: I don't know what you mean. What is a "-ve vote"?

Comment: @kunal please try this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, From City and TO city is not a drop down so you can not use `Select` class for to select it.

```
 WebDriver driver=new FirefoxDriver();
 String baseUrl = "https://www.goindigo.in";
 driver.manage().window().maximize();
 driver.get(baseUrl);

 driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")).clear(); 
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")).click();

//Select city from 
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='roundWay']/form/div[1]/ul/li[1]/input[1]")).sendKeys("Indore");

 //Select city to
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[2]/input[1]")).sendKeys("Patna");

  //select  Adults frm drop down
  driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/input")).click();

  Select adult = new Select(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"roundWay\"]/form/div[1]/ul/li[3]/div/div[1]/label[2]/select")));
  adult.selectByVisibleText("2");

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

//select date of depart
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"depart-date\"]")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"depart-date\"]")).sendKeys("18 Oct 2017");

 //select date of return
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"return-date\"]")).clear();
 driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"return-date\"]")).sendKeys("28 Oct 2017");

driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

 //Select Currency
  Select Currency = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ui-id-1")));
  Currency.selectByVisibleText("Indian Rupee");

  driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
  driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='roundWay']/form/div[2]/button")).click();
```

Comment: a bunch of code without an explanation isn't very useful. Your answer would be better if it included a description of what you did differently. Otherwise, we have to compare your code to the original line-by-line and character-by-character.

Comment: Ok you happy with it no issue:)

Comment: Kunal it is working for me Please check it once and let me know

Comment: You've made it even more confusing. You say "instead of select command" but you use `Select` multiple times.

Comment: Please provide answer it is better for questionier